# Unable to install plot.ly with wheel on python 3.7 behind constraining firewall

Tags: python, pip, plotly

I'm trying to install the `plot.ly` packages on my professional computer, i'm behind firewall, I have not the proxy information to set up a connection for `pip`.

So I download a `.whl` files and try to install it. (get it from https://pypi.org/project/plotly/)
Whatever the configuration i've tried (`anaconda 3.7, pycharm 2.7, pycharm 3.7`) i get the same message :

```
Processing c:\users\xxxx\downloads\plotly-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting retrying>=1.3.3 (from plotly==4.3.0)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
    retrying>=1.3.3 (from plotly==4.3.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for retrying>=1.3.3 (from plotly==4.3.0)
```

Comment: How about asking your IT department for the right proxy configurations?

Comment: I tried to give to pip the pac files used by IE on my compagny but it is unable to retrieve anything form PyPI.org...

Comment: I don't think that pip supports using pac files. You should ask your IT department what proxy adress and authentication you should give to `pip` to be able to connect to `pypi.org`. Everything else like downloading packages and dependencies manually is just a work around

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is trying to download the dependency `retrying`, which it can't because of your firewall. Simply download `retrying` [from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/retrying/#files), install it by typing

```
pip install <path to the downloaded file>
```

then try installing `plotly` again. Note that you will have to do this for every requirement of `plotly`.

Comment: Retrying does not exist in wheel on PyPI, only in tar.gz (for Linux i presume)

Comment: tar.gz are the source distributions and can be installed on any system (as long as the module itselfs supports that os).